# Nginx reverse proxy subdirectory vai proxy_pass for Bookstack

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm running Bookstack docker container from `https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-bookstack`

The container is running on a Ubuntu host which I'm able to use perfectly when I access it directly through its http://:

I have an nginx server running on a Windows host that I'm going to configure so that when I visit `https://myhost.tld/kb` it will proxy it to the Ubuntu host. The following is the ngnix configuration for this:

```
        location ~/kb(.*)$ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://<ubuntu-ip>:<port>$1;
        }
```

In the Bookstack container, I have the .env file APP_URL set to `https://myhost.tld/kb`

When I vist `https://myhost.tld/kb`, the any static assets don't load.

[image]

I have tried various combinations of location matches e.g `/kb/` url rewrites etc with combinations of adding/removing trailing slashes both in the location url and the proxy_pass url but to no avail.

Serving static assets directly from the Windows host is not an option as my plan is to serve multiple docker applications at different directories so I'm looking for a solution where I'm able to simply direct subdirectories to be served from different containers.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up experimenting more and finally discovered what works:

```
        location ~/kb(.*)$ {
         proxy_pass_header Authorization;
            proxy_pass http://<ip>:<port>$1$is_args$args;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_buffering off;
            client_max_body_size 0;
            proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
```

Particularly, I had to use `$is_args$args` for query terms to be forwarded.

I don't exactly understand what makes the difference between this configuration and the one I posted in the question. So if anyone can explain that it would be beneficial for the conceptual understanding of others.

Credits: https://www.techandme.se/set-up-nginx-reverse-proxy/